# Medical Statistics Attributable Risk

Tags: statistics

I have something in my notes that I cannot figure out.

[image: The Table]

[image: The Slide]

I understand that the Relative Risk, $\gamma$ here = $(\dfrac{p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}}) / (\dfrac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{22}})$ but cannot get the rest of the slide.

Answer (score 0):

The proportion with disease in the exposed and unexposed group is
$$
\frac{p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}},\quad \frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{22}}
$$
respectively. Hence *if* we assume that these proportions are the same, i.e.
$$
\frac{p_{11}}{p_{11}+p_{12}}=\frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{22}}\tag{1}$$
then
$$
p_{11}=\underbrace{(p_{11}+p_{12})\frac{p_{21}}{p_{21}+p_{22}}}_{(*)}.
$$
Let us call the expression in $(*)$ for $\tilde{p}_{11}$. Then the expression
$$
p_{11}-\tilde{p}_{11}
$$
measures the difference between the actual proportion $p_{11}$ with disease in the exposed group and the proportion $\tilde{p}_{11}$ with diseases in the exposed group *under* the assumption $(1)$. But note that the assumption $(1)$ is exactly saying that exposure has no influence on the disease, and hence the expression $p_{11}-\tilde{p}_{11}$ measures the difference in proportions (excess proportion) between what we have actually observed and what we expect to observe under the assumption that exposure is unrelated to the disease.